# android:control transfers to edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am making an app in which i have to use edit text. On opening new page, the control is automatically shifted to edittext and keyboard opens up. I want the control to be shifted, only when I touch the edittext.Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Read your question again and tell us what you understood..?

Comment: Reformat your question, it will help other to understand and help you to get proper ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your activity:

setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your activity:

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: the getwindow is giving error.. I mean to say what is get window and as getwindow is mwthod so what to use in that mehod